# Get Rid Of Video Background Empty Sides - CSS

Tags: html, css

so I'm making a website where I have a video background in my index page. This is my markup:

HTML:

```
<div class="background-video">
  <video autoplay loop poster="<?php echo ROOT_HOST; ?>res/img/video-thumbnail.jpg">
    <source src="<?php echo ROOT_HOST; ?>res/videos/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="<?php echo ROOT_HOST; ?>res/videos/bg.webm" type="video/webm" />
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background-video{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.background-video video{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

When my browser is open with full with and height of the screen it works fine, but when I change the width of the browser I get top and bottom empty space. How can I fix this and zoom into the video so it still has full width and height of the browser?

This is what happens when I change the browser with:

[image]

Comment: I would only recommend this with a video showing abstract art, not one showing real things in the world. What you're asking could cause the video to be stretched a lot if the window is tall. That would make the content of the video look weird – for example, people would look very tall and thin. The default behavior preserves the video's aspect ratio in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane not true, [**see here**](https://jsfiddle.net/4uw9y4bL/1/). If the video is to fill the background at all times then one has to be comfortable with having the video cropped along all sides in unknown amounts. Basically don't put important info in the video and treat it as _"background music,"_ you know, something to break up the monotony. Of bigger concern might be mobile. Most mobile devices do not allow autoplay of videos to conserve on data usage. In those instance you might need to replace with a poster image.

Comment: @hungerstar You're right, some methods of making the video fill the background don't have that problem. I like that solution of cropping the background video to fit, instead of stretching it to fit.